# Is there a way to extract a bzip2-archive's content into another directory without creating temporary files?

Tags: linux, extract, bzip2

I'm working with Wikipedia XML dumps and am looking for a way to extract them directly onto my ramdisk. They are simply a single xml file compressed with bzip2.

I tried

```
bzip2 -dk archive.bz2 /target/directory
```

But this ends up extracting the contents into the same directory archive.bz2 resides in. I didn't bother to wait and see if the contents get moved afterwards, as that's not what I'm looking for. Any ideas?

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45576/bunzip2-to-a-different-directory

Answer (score 0):

The samplest way I know is to do this:

```
cd /target/directory; bzip2 -d /path/to/achive/archive.bz2
```

or you can use something like:

```
bzip2 -dc /path/to/achive/archive.bz2 >/target/directory/archive
```

Comment: On my system, this seems to create a temporary file in the archive's directory, which I would like to avoid if possible.

Comment: @Adrian, set TEMP variable to somewhere, for example target directory and try again. And consider bzip2 use good amount of memory when compression is high

Comment: I tried setting `TEMP=/mnt/ramdisk` which is my target and then running your command from there, but I still get a temporary inside the source directory. What am I missing?

Comment: @Adrian, this file is actually the uncompressed archive and you can't avoid it. I personally have no info how you can set to be created somewhere else. But you can always move the archive itself

Comment: I see. I was hoping there was a way to funnel the extracted data on-the-fly to the target directory as a data stream. I'll see if I can find another solution. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Not working for me at all. Decompressed file is created in `/path/to/archive/` and not in `/target/directory/`

Comment: @diralik, please check my edited answer